# Foreach loop on stdClass Object

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, for-loop

I'm setting up a scheduling plugin for Wordpress that utilizes dev.whenIwork.com's api.

I'm newer to the PHP world, having been a front end guy - and though I have the fundamentals down, this part seems to be confusing me.

```
<?php
$wiw = new Wheniwork($wiw_token);
$shift_result = $wiw->get("shifts", array(
                                "location_id" => "106857", 
                                "start_time"  => "2014-03-05",
                                "user_id"     => "702524"
                              ));

print_r($shift_result);
```

This prints out

```
stdClass Object
(
    [start] => Wed, 02 Apr 2014 15:03:05 -0400
    [end] => Sat, 05 Apr 2014 15:03:05 -0400
    [shifts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 31577385
                    [account_id] => 66357
                    [user_id] => 702524
                    [location_id] => 106857
                    [position_id] => 160296
                    [site_id] => 65765
                    [start_time] => Wed, 02 Apr 2014 09:00:00 -0400
                    [end_time] => Wed, 02 Apr 2014 19:00:00 -0400
                    [break_time] => 1
                    [color] => 999999
                    [notes] => Website 9-12
Game 12-1
Break 1 - 1:30
Web Site 1:30 - 3:00
Game 3:00-4:00
Break 4-4:30
Website 4:30 - 5:30
Game 5:30 - 6:30
Answer emails, plan what to tackle on website next for last 30 min

                    [alerted] => 1
                    [linked_users] => 
                    [shiftchain_key] => 
                    [published] => 1
                    [published_date] => Fri, 28 Mar 2014 10:16:34 -0400
                    [notified_at] => Fri, 28 Mar 2014 10:16:35 -0400
                    [created_at] => Fri, 28 Mar 2014 09:56:36 -0400
                    [updated_at] => Wed, 02 Apr 2014 07:01:26 -0400
                    [acknowledged] => 0
                    [is_open] => 
                    [actionable] => 
                    [block_id] => 0
                )


        )

    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 702524
                    [account_id] => 66357
                    [role] => 3
                    [first_name] => First
                    [last_name] => Name
                    [avatar] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [url] => avatarurl
                            [size] => %s
                        )

                    [is_hidden] => 
                    [is_private] => 1
                    [is_deleted] => 
                    [has_email] => 1
                    [positions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 160296
                        )

                    [locations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 106857
                        )

                    [position_rates] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [position_quality] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [160296] => 3
                        )

                    [sort] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [106857] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [locations] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 106857
                    [account_id] => 66357
                    [is_default] => 0
                    [name] => Place of Employment
                    [sort] => 0
                    [max_hours] => 0
                    [address] =>    Address of Employment
                    [coordinates] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [latitude] => 0
                    [longitude] => 0
                    [ip_address] => 
                    [created_at] => Thu, 13 Mar 2014 07:22:28 -0400
                    [updated_at] => Thu, 13 Mar 2014 12:22:28 -0400
                    [is_deleted] => 
                )

        )

    [positions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 160296
                    [account_id] => 66357
                    [name] => Team Member
                    [color] => 
                    [sort] => 0
                    [created_at] => Fri, 28 Feb 2014 14:52:58 -0500
                    [updated_at] => Fri, 28 Feb 2014 14:52:58 -0500
                    [is_deleted] => 
                )

        )

    [sites] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 65765
                    [account_id] => 66357
                    [location_id] => 0
                    [name] => Place of Employment
                    [color] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [address] => 
                    [coordinates] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [latitude] => 0
                    [longitude] => 0
                    [created_at] => Fri, 28 Feb 2014 14:59:34 -0500
                    [updated_at] => Fri, 28 Feb 2014 14:59:45 -0500
                    [is_deleted] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I can individually can the location, start time, etc without a problem by doing something like

```
$location = $shift_result->shifts[0]->location_id;
```

but I just don't have the knowledge to make it "automated."

I eventually want it to be something like

```
<div id="username">
username
</div>
<div id= "starttime">
start time
</div>
```

etc.

But this is going to be for multiple employees, multiple shifts, multiple dates, etc.
I'm a bit over my head.

I'm going to keep researching of course, and if I solve this myself I'll let you guys know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($shift_result->shifts as $shifts){

    echo $shifts->first_name;  
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$shift_result->shifts` is an array of objects, so you can iterate it like so:

```
foreach($shift_results->shifts as $shift){
    echo '<p>name: ' . $shift->first_name . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Close, just no '.' period before $shift

Comment: @BrandonShutter the period is for string concatenation

Comment: Also, using your code gave me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`  Thank you though @user574632

Comment: Oh, i see i missed a closing single quote.